# Proof that the set $(1, 2]$ is a open ball in $(0, 2]$ with euclidean metric

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that  the set $M=(1, 2]$ is a open ball in $M=(0, 2]$ with euclidean metric, what I think is that I must prove that for a center $p$ and a radius $r>0$

$$B(p; r)=\left\lbrace x\in M: d(x; p)<r \right\rbrace=\left\lbrace x\in (0, 2]: |x-p|<r \right\rbrace=(1, 2]$$

We know that $0<x\leq 2$ and $p-r<x<p+r$, we could try to find the center and radius, in particular I think it works if we make $p-r=0$ so that the radius and center coincide. I tried to take $p=r=1$, but I can't come up with anything that can help me in the proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you take $p=r=1$ you get the open ball $(0,2)$. If you have $p-r=1$ then you'll get the correct left end of the interval. The other end would be $p+r$. Notice that if $p+r\leq 2$ then you have the ball $(1,p+r) \subset M$. What happens if you have $p+r \geq 2$?

Comment: $(p-r,p+r)\cap(0,2]=(1,2]$$\iff p-r=1,p+r>2$$\iff p=1+r,1+2r>2$$\iff r>\frac12,p=1+r.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B_1(2)=\{x\in(0,2]: d(x,2)\lt 1\}=(1,2]$

Comment: (+1) slightly more in general $\{x\in(0,2]: d(x,2-\delta)\lt 1-\delta\}$ for small enough delta

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(1,2]=(1,5)\cap (0,2]$ and hence is open since it's the intersection of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and the whole set $A=(0,2]$.